# All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version

Tags: android, gradle

When i updated my android studio today from version 2.2.3 to 2.3 i suddenly got this error in my build.gradle on the first compile line in dependencies

(It doesnt matter which dependencie will be at the first place but it will always give me this error):

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 25.2.0, 24.0.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.2.0 and com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:24.0.0

i have looked through my entire project and i can not find any usage of versions 24.0.0 (I have looked with ctrl + shift + F to search in entire project)

this is my build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionName "1.0"
        versionCode 1
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Comment: i had this problem too, just ignore it, or switch to beta channel of Android Studio, it should be fixed in latest release

Comment: @Alex, did you find any better solution for this except adding customtabs and vector-drawable libraries .

Comment: None of the solutions below worked for me since my problem started when i got to use facebook sdk to put a Facebook Login Button in my app. It seems to depend on support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0 in some cases but i couldn't solve it...

Comment: In my case it started appearing when I added com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1 but disappeared when I targeted the particular google play service that was needed

Answer (score 56, accepted):

> i have looked through my entire project and i can not find any usage of versions 24.0.0

It is coming as a transitive dependency from one of your other dependencies.

First, though, fix the other issues in your `build.gradle` file, as they may clear up this problem as well:

- Do not use `+` for a library version. Use a specific version.
- Do not use `play-services`. Use the specific dependencies for the specific pieces of the Play Services SDK that you want. `play-services` brings in *all* of Play Services, making your app much bigger than it needs to be and slowing down your build times a lot.
- Replace `com.mcxiaoke.volley` with the official Volley artifact (`com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0`)

If none of those clear up the issue, you can run a Gradle dependency report to see what your full tree of dependencies are. From there, you will see which one of your libraries is asking for a different version of the Android Support libraries. For whatever it is asking for, you can ask for it directly with the `25.2.0` version, or use Gradle's other conflict resolution approaches to arrange to get the same version.

Comment: To see a tree of the dependencies: `./gradlew -q dependencies myModuleName:dependencies --configuration compile`.  Something was using an outdated support-v4, so I added the latest to my dependencies.

Comment: running following command starts downloading gradle zip. and after that nothing happens as: 
"Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip"

Comment: ohh. it shown the dependencies after running command second time.:)

Comment: Thanks it worked. I had bundle `play-services` now with specific `play-services-location` its fine

Answer (score 63):

To elaborate on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42582204/1428514), proper dependency resolution for the support library case is as follows:

Don't just add transitive dependencies as direct dependencies to force their versions; this is semantically the wrong thing to do (if you ever remove the dependency that brought in the transitive dependency, you now have a leftover dependency you're not actually using).

Do the following:

In your root `build.gradle`, you should already have

```
ext {
    supportlib_version = '27.1.1'
    ...
}
```

and be using this property in your e.g. `app/build.gradle` like

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportlib_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportlib_version"
    ...
}
```

Now, in your root `build.gradle`, have

```
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "$supportlib_version"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

that is, in every module and every configuration, when resolving dependencies, if it's a support lib (but not the multidex ones (there may be more exceptions)), force the version to your standardized support lib version.

---

Now in the age of jetpack and jetifier, it appears prudent to employ a variation (assuming you have migrated to the androidx versions):

Your e.g. `app/build.gradle` will now contain androidx dependencies, but libraries you use may still transitively pull in supportlib dependencies, which you still want on the same version (namely, 28.0.0) so that they can get properly jetified at build time.

So keep the root `build.gradle` parts as is, using `28.0.0` for the `supportlib_version`.

Comment: I like this answer the best though I could definitely see a case where a quirk in the support library causes a dependency expecting an earlier version to cause an issue, and it is not readily apparent what is happening.

Comment: True that - although that is sort of bad luck then; you'd be in the same boat if you require the same support lib dependency as that other dependency that cannot deal with the current/a later support lib version.

Comment: this is more of a better solution in the long run than patching everything

Comment: @Jule - is ` supportlib_version ` a reserved? Or I can name whatever I want?

Comment: @RoCk whatever you like - although as a reader of your code, I'd expect some variation of that name for that purpose. This is a useful pattern in general when you have several artifacts using the same version of a thing - e.g. retrofit with matching adapters and converts. Then I'd also define `retrofit_version` and use it in the same way.

Comment: In my case subprojects{} not working. Just keeping configurations.all {} worked.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 23):

### **For all cases, not just for these versions or libraries:**

Pay attention to the little information window that say something about the error, it says the examples that you have to change and add.

### You can't see the usages because its use is probably internal of another library (like google play services or squareup).

**Just compile all examples that the little information window says**, in your case:

> ***Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.2.0 and
>   com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:24.0.0***

**Your**

> *com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.2.0*

**is version 25.2.0, and your**

> *com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:24.0.0*

**is version 24.0.0, so you have to add the mediarouter with the same version:**

```
com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.2.0
```

And do that for every example that the little information window says; in your case **all the libraries that doesn't have the version 25.2.0.**

**You have to sync the gradle after you fix the indicated library to see the next library and package that you have to change.**

Comment: This is the right answer. Saved my day, thanks

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Same problem happened to me. What I just did that added these two lines

```
compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.2.0'
```

problem solved. I also deleted my previous version of gradle folder.

Comment: Why did this work?

Comment: @IanWambai, try to set all support libraries the same version and clean project.

Comment: I do not need these libs , this is not the right solution. Why to unnecessarily add libraries.

Comment: Worked for me, the warning itself tells you which libs to compile.

Answer (score 8):

you can add

```
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.2.0'
```

and by right clicking in *gradle* dependency you can add the conflicting dependencies.
for me it was

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.2.0'
```

Comment: Adding the three dependencies solved my problem. Thank you +1

Answer (score 8):

Add this to the very end of your build.gradle (Module:app):

```html
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Replace the '25.3.1' with the version of android support library that you want to use , the version must be above the version of your compileSdk version .

Comment: Thanks for this solution, I can't find library that required v27 and this fix my problem in a moment.

Comment: This adds no information over the other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42718231/2308683

Comment: this solution worked for me. spent hours in vain before this. thanx man.

Answer (score 4):

I have same problem in Android studio 2.3

**before:**
[image]

Then,I try:

```
./gradlew -q dependencies app --configuration compile

+--- project :lib
+--- com.jonathanfinerty.once:once:1.2.2
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
+--- com.zhy:base-rvadapter:3.0.3
|    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0 -> 25.3.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 -> 25.3.1
|              +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1
|              |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|              +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.3.1
|              |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|              |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|              +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1
|              |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|              |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|              +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1
|              |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|              |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|              \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:25.3.1
|                   +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|                   +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|                   +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1 (*)
|                   \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1 (*)
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.11.0
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0 (*)
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0
+--- com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0
|    +--- com.jakewharton:butterknife-annotations:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.1.0 -> 25.3.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.1.0 -> 25.3.1
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0
+--- org.litepal.android:core:1.5.1
+--- com.orhanobut:logger:1.15
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1 (*)
```

the base-rvadapter library not include 25.3.1:

```
com.zhy:base-rvadapter:3.0.3
|    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0
```

Finally,I add a line:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

design include appcompat-v7,and base-rvadapter link 25.3.1.

```
+--- project :lib
+--- com.jonathanfinerty.once:once:1.2.2
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
+--- com.zhy:base-rvadapter:3.0.3
|    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0 -> 25.3.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1
|         |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1
|              +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|              \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.11.0
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0 (*)
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0
+--- com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0
|    +--- com.jakewharton:butterknife-annotations:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.1.0 -> 25.3.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.1.0 -> 25.3.1
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0
+--- org.litepal.android:core:1.5.1
+--- com.orhanobut:logger:1.15
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.3.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:25.3.1
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1 (*)
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1 (*)
\--- com.android.support:design:25.3.1
     +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 (*)
     +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 (*)
     +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1 (*)
     \--- com.android.support:transition:25.3.1
          +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
          \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 (*)
```

**after:**[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification) it is pointed that adding this line will remove the error.

```
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.2.0'
```

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: Try the solution by @ Brandon Zamudio above

Comment: This is **not** a catch-all solution to the error. This one line only works if that's the outdated library

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Android Studio 2.3 requires to declare external dependencies explicitly. The dependencies are customtabs and palette-v7.

You would need to explicitly add the following two external dependencies/packages in build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.2.0'
```

I think this would solve the issue.

Comment: this worked for me

Comment: I must add that only palette library was necessary

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'` with the specific package(s) you are using (see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42374426/3495069)

Answer (score 1):

Remove or update the Following Dependency

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
```

or only  add the selective services  like this

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:10.2.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.2.4'
```

Answer (score -1):

Make all the dependencies of same version or latest version in your case replace support library versions with 25.2.0 .

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. Please correct it or delete it.

Comment: @muttonUp Maybe you're right (I don't know) but the "not an answer" flag is for answers that don't even try to be an answer, f.e. new questions, comments, or "thank you" responses. It's better to downvote answers if you think they miss the mark.

Comment: I solved my issue with this...that's probably the right answer for me . You to try a shot.

Comment: @NeeleshJaisinghani com.squareup:otto latest version is 1.3.8, so how would changing its to version 25.2.0 do anything but break your code?

Answer (score -2):

Use specific versions instead of `+`. For example, 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'

And use specific SDKs which you are using instead of adding the entire Play-SDKs package. For example:

```
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.0'
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
```

This helped me resolve the issue.