# All com.android.support libraries must use the exact version

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I came across this issue

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing version can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 24.0.0, 23.4.0, 23.1.1. Examples include
>   com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0 and
>   com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0

I have been reading about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581963/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version)

From what i gather i can find the "offset version" using

```
./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration compile
```

The above then results in:

```
compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- project :library
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 -> 24.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:9.8.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.8.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.8.0
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:9.8.0
|    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.8.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.8.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.8.0 (*)
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.13.1
|    +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0
|    |    +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|    |    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0
|    |         \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|    +--- com.android.support:customtabs:23.4.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0 -> 24.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 -> 24.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 -> 24.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 -> 24.0.0 (*)
+--- com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0
+--- com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+ -> 2.1.9
|    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3
|    \--- com.koushikdutta.async:androidasync:2.1.9
+--- com.ivankocijan:MagicViews:1.0.4
+--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.6
|    +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.15
|    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:beta:1.2.3
|    |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.15
|    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.11
|    |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.15
|    \--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-core:2.3.15
|         +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.15
|         \--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.11 (*)
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.5
|    +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.14 -> 1.3.15
|    \--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-core:2.3.13 -> 2.3.15 (*)
\--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0
     \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.8.0
          +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.8.0 (*)
          +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.8.0
          |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.8.0 (*)
          |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:9.8.0 (*)
          \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:9.8.0
               +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.8.0 (*)
               +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:9.8.0
               |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.8.0 (*)
               |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.8.0 (*)
               \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.8.0 (*)
```

Gradle:

[image]

My question is.

*Even if i have now found the dependencies with the wrong version, how can i change that ?*

I have tried to compile them using the correct version, but the warning remains.

Comment: what buildToolsVersion are you using??

Comment: Hi. compileSdkVersion 23  buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use same `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion` as Support library 
e.g.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:24.2.0'
 }
```

You can see here Support Library, `compiledSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion` use same version. Just try it and see if it fixes your issues.

Comment: Actually by doing that i get the error: Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (24.0.0) is too low for project ':xx'. Minimum required is 25.0.0

Comment: okay so why not change that 25.0.0?? I mean just change Support library version and compiledSdkVersion to 25 as well..

Comment: Yes that seems to remove the error, but which consequences will this have for users or older devices ?

Comment: Oh! No, nothing negative.. they are just newer versions of Support library and buildtools which are better for older devices because they have new bugs fixes and improvements.

Comment: With the new android gradle plugin 3.x you no longer need to specify a version for the build tools (so, you can now remove the android.buildToolsVersion property).
By default, the plugin automatically uses the minimum required build tools version for the version of Android plugin you're using.