# Can't find Standalone SDK Manager to download 25.3.1 SDK

Tags: android, gradle, sdk, synchronization

I have an (outdated) project that needs the 25.3.1 SDK, but I can't find a way to download the sdk manager to sync the project.

I find a lot of description like Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager and then choose what you need.

The official documentation say the same https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#sdk-manager

To upgrade the project is unfortunately not an option.

I use macOS, Android Studio 2.3.3

Gradle:
 `buildToolsVersion '25.3.1'`

So how can I download SDK 25.3.1?

Thanks for help

Comment: What do you mean with 25.3.1 SDK?

Comment: When I try to sync buildToolsVersion 25.3.1, AndroidTools say, that 25.3.1 doesnt exist anymore. In web I found that I need sdk 25.3.1

Comment: There was never a 25.3.1 of the build tools. The only thing that I can think of that ever had a 25.3.1 number would be [the support libraries](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#25-3-1).

Comment: Thats it. I'm sorry. I didn't realize that I'm handling around with support libraries. I had a kind of problem like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581963/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version/42582204#42582204 

Thank you!