# All support libraries must use the exact same version specification.Found 27.0.1.26.1.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library

I am struggling with gradle build error i followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42582204/6527410) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42635781/6527410) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42605875/6527410) but none working for me. It was working fine but once i update Exoplayer lib to 2.6 from current but even after reverse i am getting same error. Also when i tried to followed First answer i am getting 7000+ errors in gradle build.

[image]

My libraries

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use 27.0.1 instead of 26.1.0.  Do this for all current dependencies and if the error still pops up, add the 26.1.0 library it mentions to your build.gradle as version 27.0.1

Continue until the error is fixed

Comment: for this i need to change compile sdk version to 27

Comment: Yes, is that an issue?  You should use the latest compile sdk version anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Ritu you can update support lib version to 27.0.1 to make it work you also need to change compile SDK version to 27
No need to change target SDk it can be whatever below 27.
One more tips use gradle variable to use version so that it can be consistent and can be changed easily

Edit
Also you need to include google maven path

```
  maven {                                 
            url 'https://maven.google.com/' 
            name 'Google'
        }
```

Or `google()` if using latest gradle version ie. 3+

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to update all your dependency to use newest support library version. 
There is a chance that not all library will be use the same version of sub-component. Try to exclude libraries that use different (older) version of support library using:

```
 {  exclude group: 'com.android.support'}
```

try this on specific libray :)
P.S. Good lack with architecture components :)